# Use Conda and Python on a system without administration permission

Tags: python, windows, conda

I have a Windows laptop that I cannot install anything on. I need to use Python for data analysis. I'd like to create an conda environment on another laptop, move it to that laptop, and use it.

Is it possible? I have to note that laptop does not have any internet access.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Python directly onto a portable drive/usb. You could also, move it from the usb drive to your local directory (C:\Users\name\Python...). You just need to set the path to where python is installed.

I did this with Python and VS Code. Can use it wherever without need for admin rights.

Comment: yeah, I'm looking for something like that. Can you explain it in more details? for example  how did you connect python to the that portable VScode?